# Getting Syntax error when trying the "Finally" statment

Tags: java, android, syntax, syntax-error

I've put in a "finally" statement, but I get Syntax error, I don't have any idea on how to correct them, I've tried everything, but to no avail. My class get's the string from the two edit text fields, if the checkbox is checked it saves the two strings to a file, to be called up later, then, if there's nothing in the edit text's, it displays a toast. If it's their first time, their data(user and pass it saved) and, if they've done this before via checking the file, it goes to another class via an intent. Oh, sorry for my bad code, I'm a new Java programmer and I'm trying to make it as neat as possible. Secondly, if there's a better way to code, than I've done, please feel free to change it,

Thanks.

Errors marked with an ^.

Code:

```
Button send;
    EditText user;
    EditText pass;
    CheckBox staySignedIn;
    FileOutputStream Fos;
    String a;
    String b;
    String string = a;
    String string2 = b;


    String FILENAME = "userandpass";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogIn);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTuser);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTpassword);
        staySignedIn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Cbstay);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);

        File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);
        if (file.exists())
            ;
        Intent i = new Intent(LogIn.this, ChatService.class);
        startActivity(i); ^
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bLogIn:
            if (pass.length() == 0)
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Try to type in your username and password again!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else if (user.length() == 0)
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Try to type in your username and password again!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else {

            if (staySignedIn.isChecked()) {


                String a = user.getText().toString();
                String b = pass.getText().toString();
                File f = new File(FILENAME);
                try {
                    Fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    if (Fos != null) {
                    Fos.write(a.getBytes());
                    Fos.write(b.getBytes());
                    }
                    Fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace(); ^
                finally  {
                        String u = user.getText().toString();
                        String p = pass.getText().toString();
                        Bundle send = new Bundle();
                        send.putString("key", u);
                        send.putString("key1", p);
                        Intent c = new Intent(LogIn.this, logincheck.class);
                        c.putExtra("key", u);
                        c.putExtra("key1", p);
                        startActivity(c);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Were signing you in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        break;
                    }




            }
        }

    } ^
```

Errors

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block  LogIn.java  /Banana Phone/src/com/gta5news/bananaphone  line 53 Java Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody  LogIn.java  /Banana Phone/src/com/gta5news/bananaphone  line 36 Java Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody LogIn.java  /Banana Phone/src/com/gta5news/bananaphone  line 53 Java Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody LogIn.java  /Banana Phone/src/com/gta5news/bananaphone  line 107    Java Problem
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't close the second catch statement :

```
} catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

}  //<=HERE ADD }
            finally  {
```

Common structure is :

```
try{
}
catch(...){  // since jdk7 you can put all your exception on one line
}
finally{
}
```

EDIT :

and replace :

```
else {

        if (staySignedIn.isChecked()) {
```

by

```
 else if (staySignedIn.isChecked()) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error, but I've still got two more, I've tried everything, but it won't go away.

Comment: if (file.exists())
            ;
        Intent i = new Intent(LogIn.this, ChatService.class); there is a ";" alone, drop hit and use bracket if the if statement does not apply to only the next statement.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the closing bracket.

```
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            finally  {
```

should be:

```
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally  {
```

Since you didn't post the whole Java file, I can't verify the whole code. You might try adding another closing bracket at the end of your code snippet where you marked the `^`.

Comment: Yes! that fixed one the errors, I've still got two more, I marked them with a ^.

Comment: The last error can be fixed by adding a `}`. I can't tell you what is wrong with the first error. We need the error message to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot include any statements between the try and catch block.you have included "fos.close() in your public "void onClick(View v)" function.